# Programmatically determine order in which UIView items should be read by VoiceOver

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, first-responder, voiceover

I am making my iPhone app accessible. VoiceOver is pretty impressive. When a user uses VoiceOver, it automatically reads off the items on the screen and allows the user to double-tap anywhere on the screen to select that item. However, I want VoiceOver to read the items in a specific order, but it always begins with the UINavigationBar items including the back button. I don't want these items *not* to be read at all, I just want to start with a specific item. Is there a VoiceOver-equivalent of "firstResponder"?

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

There is a protocol called `UIAccessibilityContainer` that is implemented by NSObject. It enables you to customize the container behaviour using these three methods:

- `accessibilityElementCount`
- `accessibilityElementAtIndex:`
- `indexOfAccessibilityElement:`

If you have a main view where you want to control the order of the accessibility elements you would just implement these three methods and return the suitable view/index. One more thing is that the container view cannot be an accessibility element itself so you should override `isAccessibilityElement:` and return `NO`;

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
    return NO;
}
```

---

### Example implementations

I suggest that you either have an array of all the views in the order you want them to appear or use the `tag` property if you don't use it for anything else. The implementation of the protocol becomes super simple.

#### Array of elements

I'm assuming that you have an array called `accessibleElements` that store the elements in the correct order.

```
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {
    return self.accessibleElements.count;
}

- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return self.accessibleElements[index]; 
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element {
    return [self.accessibleElements indexOfObject:element];
}
```

#### Tagged elements

I'm assuming that your subviews are tagged continuously from 0 up to the number of subviews.

```
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {
    return self.subviews.count;
}

- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    // Not that self should have a tag<0 or tag>count otherwise it will 
    // return itself for that tag instead of the element you want it to.
    return [self viewWithTag:index]; 
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element {
    return ((UIView *)element).tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, setting UIAccessibilityTraitSummaryElement on one item can do this. (My game seems too dynamic for this to help much.)

Comment: Or possibly not — I may misunderstand UIAccessibilityTraitSummaryElement, it may simply be what is spoken at screen entry. Which is not the same as the focused item.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** You can specify the order of element in **accessibilityElements** property

```
self.accessibilityElements = [lable1, label2, label2].compactMap {$0}
```

For specifying the order of CollectionView cells.

```
 // MARK: collection view accessibility order
    override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int {
        return numberOfItemInSection()// specify your items count
    }

    override func accessibilityElement(at index: Int) -> Any? {
        return collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
    }
```